# Member of group cannot cd into directory

Tags: permissions, users, groups

I have a folder `testfolder` with owner `tuser1` and group `testgroup`.

`ls -l` shows this:

```
drwxr-x--- 24 tuser1 testgroup 4096 Apr 17 13:33 testfolder
```

`tuser2` also belongs to `testgroup`.

`getent group testgroup` shows:

```
testgroup:x:519:tuser2,tuser1
```

But `tuser2` cannot cd into `testfolder`, it says "permission denied", how is this possible?

Comment: You need to log out / log back in after changes are made to groups for them to be effective.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `id` and `getfacl testfolder`? Thanks.